# data binding update when value changes, not when tabbing out

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

Is there a property or setting to force a bound control in Winforms to update the object it is bound to when the input value, either in a textbox or whatever, actually changes?

And not after the control is tabbed out of.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you have already bound the textbox to something:

- Select the textbox in the designer
- Click property "databindings"
- Click property "advanced"
- In this dialog look for the "datasource update mode"
- Select **onpropery changed instead of onvalidate**

Now the datasource gets updated on every change of the text property of the textbox.